# Angular JS : $routeProvider with dynamic url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, route-provider

I have a menu that show different groups Name to which a user belongs . I prepared a template page so that when a user choose one of the menu's GROUPS , the template's fields change.

```
<li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i>Home </a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="collapse" ng-init="getAllGroupsofUser()"data-target="#groups">My Groups</a>
     <ul id="groups" class="collapse">
       <li ng-repeat="group in groupsofUser" ng-controller="groupsCTRL"><a 
           ng-click="openPage(group)">{{group.name}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

The Groups were successfully shown in the menu.
I'm using ng-view and $routeProvider.

my $routeProvider

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
   function($routeProvider) {
     $routeProvider
       .when('/', {
         templateUrl: 'home.html',
         controller:"MyController"
       })
       .when('/group/:groupname', {
         templateUrl: "groupTemplate.html",
         controller:"groupsCTRL"
       }).
       otherwise({
       redirectTo: '/'
     });
 }]);
```

my controller

```
app.controller( 'groupsCTRL',[ '$scope', '$http' , '$location', '$routeParams' ,function($scope, $http,$location,$routeParams){

     $scope.groupeName= $routeParams.groupname;

     $scope.openPage = function(group) {
        $scope.groupselected = group;
          console.log( "group: "+$scope.groupselected.id);
          location.href = "#/group/"+group.name;
    }

}]);
```

my template

```
<div class="row" >
      <h1 class="page-header">Groupe {{groupeName}} </h1>
</div>
<div class="row">
     {{groupselected.id}}
</div>
```

my problem is that the groupeName is displayed , but the groupselected.id is only displayed in the console (because i used  `console.log( "group: "+$scope.groupselected.id);`)

please help me , I need to know if the group was passed to the page because in the next step I'll need to show informations about that selected group .

Comment: you need to use `$location.path("#/group/"+group.name);` instead of `location.href = "#/group/"+group.name;`

Comment: I 've changed it to $location.path("#/group/"+group.name);  but this way   the url has not changed and my page was not called

Comment: basically you need to call `$scope.$apply()` after it, will work for your case

Comment: sorry , I'm  a begginner, I just have to write $scope.$apply() in my function ?? I didn't know how to do it

Comment: you could write `$scope.openPage = function(group) {
        $scope.groupselected = group;
          console.log( "group: "+$scope.groupselected.id);
          $location.path("/group/"+group.name);
          if(!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply()
    }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by creating a new RESTful Web Service to get the Group By Name (since it's unique)

```
//get Group by Name 
         $scope.getGroupByName = function(groupname){
              $scope.group=[];
            $http({method: 'GET', url: '/getGroupByName/'+groupname}).
             success(function(result) {
                $scope.group = result.data; 
                    }).
                    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                      // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                      // or server returns response with an error status.
                    });
          };
```

to which I can pass my groupeName and get the group

Answer (score 1):

Use `$location.path` instead of `location.href`. Also In order to apply location changes,  & then you need to run digest cycle.

**Code**

```
$scope.openPage = function(group) {
    $scope.groupselected = group;
    console.log( "group: "+$scope.groupselected.id);
    $location.path("/group/"+group.name);
    if(!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply();
};
```

Comment: thanks , but it's just like my solution , Still can't show groupselected on the page

Comment: @marwa  did you find any solution on this ?

Comment: well , I 've created a new RESTful Web Service to get the Group By Name (since I can get the name  `$scope.groupeName= $routeParams.groupname` and it's unique)  and then  I can get all the group information